# Resetting the PRAM on a PowerMac G5 using Terminal 1.5.1

Tags: mac, terminal.app, osx-tiger, ppc

Need to reset the PRAM using Terminal 1.5 on a PowerMac G5 running Mac OS X 10.4.11 Tiger.

However, when I enter the command in Terminal:

```
sudo nvram -c
```

> c in not an option for that version of Terminal.

What alternate command can I use to do this?

Comment: What's this got to do with Linux?

Comment: The `-c` option should be passed to the `nvram` command.  Type `man nvram` and maybe `which nvram` to check out what command you're running and the options.  Please paste an actual picture of what you're typing in the Terminal.  It's VERY odd that that command should be giving that error, where it's mentioning Terminal itself.

Comment: What are you hoping to gain by clearing it? Most people seem to do it "just in case". It only holds sound volume, display resolution, startup disk selection, time zone, and recent kernel panic information.

Answer (score 2):

There is a boot keyboard combination for that:

Reboot your Mac and then immediately hold down the <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> keys.

Comment: I don't remember exactly but there might be a chime if done correctly.

Comment: You hold the key combo at the boot chime, then keep holding til it chimes again.